# Error rendering control. The server block is not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

This is user control page

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserInfoBoxControl.ascx.cs"
 Inherits="WebApplication3.UserInfoBoxControl" %>

<b>Information about <%@ this.UserName %></b><br /><br />

<%@ this.UserName %> is <%@ this.UserAge %> years old and lives in <%@ this.UserCountry %>
```

Controller CS file

```
public partial class UserInfoBoxControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private string userName;
    private int userAge;
    private string userCountry;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }

    public int UserAge
    {
        get { return userAge; }
        set { userAge = value; }
    }

    public string UserCountry
    {
        get { return userCountry; }
        set { userCountry = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

webform on which i want to implement this.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="My" TagName="UserInfoBoxControl" src="~/UserInfoBoxControl.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>No one</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>World</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Universe</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />
    <My:UserInfoBoxControl runat="server" ID="MyUserInfoBoxControl" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Getting error** 
Error rendering control: Myuserinfoboxcontrol
the server block is now well formed.

**i am not getting how to rectify it**

i want to implement user control on my webform but i am getting this error. Need help. thanks

Comment: I suspect there is some issue with the inheritance of WebApplication3.UserInfoBoxControl. Include the code and the full error message to your question

Comment: @StefanE can u please help me with that

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, I repeat that you need to update your question with what I wrote above to be able to help any further

Answer (score 1):

i guess this:

```
<b>Information about <%@ this.UserName %></b><br /><br />

<%@ this.UserName %> is <%@ this.UserAge %> years old and lives in <%@ 
this.UserCountry %>
```

should be:

```
<b>Information about <%= this.UserName %></b><br /><br />

<%= this.UserName %> is <%= this.UserAge %> years old and lives in <%= 
this.UserCountry %>
```